# bin and transpose in R

Tags: r, transpose, binning, dimensionality-reduction

I am still getting the hang of R and coding in general, so bear with me on this.

**my problem** This is a dimension reduction idea I have consisting of three steps. I need help with the first two.

1. bin rows
2. transpose the binned rows into new columns so the columns will increase by number of bin, rows decrease by number of bins
3. Perform PCA to then reduce columns

So the data would go from this:

```
  A  B  C  D
1 W1 X1 Y1 Z1
2 W2 X2 Y2 Z2
3 W3 X3 Y3 Z3
4 W4 X4 Y4 Z4
5 W5 X5 Y5 Z5
6 W6 X6 Y6 Z6
```

so, if I bin by 2 and transpose it would look something like this:

```
   A   A   B   B   C   C   D   D
1 W1   W2  X1  X2  Y1  Y2  Z1  Z2
2 W3   W4  X3  X4  Y3  Y4  Z3  Z4
3 W5   W6  X5  X6  Y5  Y6  Z5  Z6
```

I'm pretty sure I need to nest bin and transpose in some sort of function, but I'm not sure which comes first, or really at all how to approach this, so any suggestions will help!

I really hope this makes some sense, let me know how I can rephrase if needed!

**EDIT**
I am working with integer datatypes, here is a snippet of my actual data I'd like to bin and expand.

```
> head(dataset[1:4])
   EMG1  EMG2  EMG3  EMG4
1 32744 32571 32935 32279
2 32788 32934 32767 32624
3 32828 33202 32587 32377
4 32870 33269 32423 32954
5 32838 33319 32126 32721
6 32903 33502 32652 32151
```

Comment: Try `do.call(cbind, split(dat, 1:nrow(dat) %% 2 == 0))`

Comment: @markus Is there a way to do cbind using t() for transpose?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming these letter digit entries as not supposed to be stand ins for numerics, I would first run this:

```
dat[] <- lapply(dat, as.character) # ensures we get rid of factors
```

This uses recycling of logical indices inside a function that gets serially applied across your dataframe to create two lists from each column. That is then coerced to a dataframe. The initial result `res` has rather odd names which get shortened with some simple regex work.

```
 res <- data.frame( lapply(dat, 
         function(cl){list( list(cl[c(TRUE,FALSE)], 
                            list(cl[!c(TRUE,FALSE)]) )) }))
 names(res) <- sub("\\..+$", "", names(res))

> res
   A  A  B  B  C  C  D  D
1 W1 W2 X1 X2 Y1 Y2 Z1 Z2
2 W3 W4 X3 X4 Y3 Y4 Z3 Z4
3 W5 W6 X5 X6 Y5 Y6 Z5 Z6
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. The letter digit entries _are_ stand-ins for numerics. Sorry for the confusion.